# bind custom list of items in a listview Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I'm trying to use the listview in Xamarin forms, here is my code

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stackMap" Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Text="Seleziona cantiere" Margin="7,0,0,0" TextColor="#3880c4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" FontSize="Medium" />
        <ListView x:Name="listView">
          <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
                  <StackLayout>
                    <!--<Image Source="{Binding image}" />-->
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#f35e20" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Type}" TextColor="#503026" />
                  </StackLayout>
              </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
          </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
      </StackLayout>
```

and the codebehind in load method:

```
var cities = new List<VeggieViewModel>();
        cities.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "okkk", Type = "okkk", Image = "okkkk" });
        cities.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "okkk", Type = "okkk", Image = "okkkk" });
        cities.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "okkk", Type = "okkk", Image = "okkkk" });
        cities.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "okkk", Type = "okkk", Image = "okkkk" });
        cities.Add(new VeggieViewModel { Name = "okkk", Type = "okkk", Image = "okkkk" });

        listView.ItemsSource = cities;
```

the class object:

```
 public class VeggieViewModel
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Type;
        public string Image;
    }
```

my poblem is that it does not print anything in the listview, I print properly and produces the list view of the items he has inside, but does not print anything.
Where am I doing wrong ?

**SOLUTION**
sorry for my mistake of distracting :(
the solution is to put `{get; set;}` Object Class.
thank you all.
Still I leave the question for another distracted like me :)

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted

Comment: i have add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `{get; set;}`; this solution works:

```
 public class VeggieViewModel
    {
        public string Name {get; set;}
        public string Type {get; set;}
        public string Image {get; set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class VeggieViewModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Type {get; set;}
    public string Image {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: A little explanation as to how and why your answer could work would be nice. Now it's just a piece of code.